# App stuck in white screen in iOS ionic 5 app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, wkwebview

I pushed newly created ionic app to test flight and got bellow error.
    ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

```
Follow the below steps to Fix it.
1) Created new ionic app (Ionic version 5.0.0)
2) Added iOS platform (ionic cordova platfrom add ios@5.1.1)
3) After adding platform below plugins will get added to package.json & config.xml
     Package.json : 

    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",


    Config.xml
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.1">



4) Removed Webview plugin as suggested ionic Cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview.
5) Removed platform ionic cordova platform rm ios
6) Added plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine@1.2.1 --save
7) Added preference attribute CordovaWebViewEngine to the config.xml as below.
8) Added feature attribute CDVWKWebViewEngine to the config.xml as below.
9) Added preference WKWebViewOnly to the config.xml as below.
    "<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </platform>"
10) Added ios platform "ionic cordova platform add ios@5.1.1 --save"
11) Build project "ionic cordova build iOS"
12) Open project in XCode and try to launch app in Simulator and iPhone getting white screen after splash screen


Now app got stuck in white screen after splash screen, Please help me to resolve this issue.


Thanks 
Anshul
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Such a waste of time with IONIC. I should have used flutter instead...